# Find and index item inside a list of lists

Tags: python

This is for my python algorithms class:
So I have list `database` which should have lists 1, 2 and 3 (`item`) inside of it. I have to find a way to find items inside lists 1, 2 and 3 but also print the index of the list which that item belongs inside list `database`

This is how it's setup:

```
database = []
name = input('type the name')
desc = input('type the description')
item = [name, desc]
database.append(item)
```

I've tried making a variable that scans for the specific item inside the lists of lists which kinda worked, but I can only make it show that this item exists in one of the `item` lists and can't actually index the list of which that item belongs to inside `database`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> database = [["pizza", "description-of-pizza"], ["burger", "description-of-burger"], ["soup", "description-of-soup"]]
...
>>> for index, (name, description) in enumerate(database):
...   if name == "burger":
...     print(index, name, description)
... 
1 burger description-of-burger
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `enumerate` function.

You give it an *iterable* (items through which you can iterate using a *for* loop), e. g. lists, strings, etc. and it gives you index, at which some item is stored within that iterable, and that very item.

For example, the code below:

```
for index, symbol in enumerate("Hi!"):
    print(f"Index: {index}. Symbol: '{symbol}'.")
```

Will print the following:

`Index: 0. Symbol: 'H'.`

`Index: 1. Symbol: 'i'.`

`Index: 2. Symbol: '!'.`

`enumerate` with other iterables will work the same.

The code that does your job:

```
database = []

for i in range(3):
    name = input('Type the name: ')
    desc = input('Type the description: ')
    item = [name, desc]
    database.append(item)
    # database.append([name, desc]) - shorter

for index, item in enumerate(database):
    # Do something with index and item
    print(f'Index: {index}. Item: {item}')
```